# iOS IAPs - Handling restore when no previous purchase was made

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase, restore

I'm a bit of newbie, but have pretty much taught myself to code from scratch over the last three months (thanks youtube!). So please excuse me if I'm making an obvious error.

My app is pretty much ready to go, but I have one bug that I can't seem to find a solution to online.

Essentially, my IAP process is working correctly, as is the restore function most of the time. I hit a bug, however, when a user presses the restore button but has not made any non-consumable in-app purchases before. My app just stays in the 'restoring' state with a spinner and interactionEvents ignored.

I am not sure where to place the code to cancel the spinner and end ignoring interaction events in a situation where the paymentQueue appears to be returning no restored transactions.

I have tried to place this under .default for the following:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState
```

but it doesn't not appear to be working.

Has anyone encountered this before and have suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Regards,
Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initiate restoration, the observer method `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is called with the previously purchased transactions.  If no purchases have been made, then this method is not called.

Once the restoration of purchases is complete then the [`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran) observer method is called.  This is the method where you should update your UI to indicate that restoration is complete; hide the spinner etc.

Comment: Oh wow! haha, I even have that function in my code but it just did nothing.

Makes sense, however when I move my UI update functions (remove spinners etc...) from within the 'paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions...' function to the 'paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_:)' the UI now doesn't update for either situation where:
1) User has previously made a non-consumable IAP purchase, or
2) User has never made an IAP purchase before...

What am I missing?!

Comment: Are you dispatching your UI updates on the main queue?

Comment: Paulw11, thanks so much for your speedy responses!
Okay, so to tell you the truth I'm not really sure... but I haven't gone ahead and consciously created any additional queues, so I presume the restore is happening on the main queue in the following function:  `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`. We know that function runs because we get output in the console from the switch transaction.transactionState ...  case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored  function. <Continued below>

Comment: <From Above> The UI Updates is happening in the `func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue)` function... How would I tell whether the original restore and the UI updates are both happening in the main queue? From what I can see, it appears they are. Yet QueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished appears not to run.

Comment: Paulw11... I was being a complete idiot/N00b. my `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` function and `updatedTransactions` function were sitting inside `viewDidLoad` - therefore not running when the restore completed or failed. Thank you for your advice!